# Call custom func on UIView in Array

Tags: arrays, swift, uiview

I have a Array with different UIViews, but these UIViews have the same method who does different things, I would like to call these methods. My array is  created as  than when I tried to call the method, it do no exist into a UIView Class.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var pages:Array<UIView>  = []

    let view1:View1 = View1(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0 ,  100 , 100))
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    pages.append(view1)

    let view2:View2 = View2(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100 ,  100 , 100))
    view2.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    pages.append(view2)

    let view3:View3 = View3(frame: CGRectMake(200, 200 ,  100 , 100))
    view3.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    pages.append(view3)

    //This work
    for myView in pages {
      self.view.addSubview(myView)
    }

    // I would like to call a generic function into a uiview class into array
    for myView in pages {
      myView.generic()
    }

  }

  class View1: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect  ) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func generic(){
      println("A, B, C")
    }

  }

  class View2: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect  ) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func generic(){
      println("X, Y, Z")
    }

  }

  class View3: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect  ) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func generic(){
      println("1, 2, 3")
    }

  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of treating these views as `UIView`, their common super class, we can declare a protocol and make these views all conform to it.

```
protocol GenericProtocol {
    func generic()
}
```

Now, in the class definitions, add this conformance:

```
class View1: UIView, GenericProtocol { /* ... */ }
// for each class
```

And now, let's make our array hold `GenericProtocol` objects:

```
var pages = [GenericProtocol]()
```

After we've filled it up, we can now `forin` over it, and call anything that's declared in `GenericProtocol` on its members:

```
for page in pages {
    page.generic()
}
```

Comment: Peace of cake, Thank you